# Code Contracts and Fluent API with EF Code First Sample

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-contracts, fluent-interface

Consider the following code snippet:

```
public partial class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        Contract.Assume(modelBuilder != null);

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasOptional(x => x.Profile).WithRequired(x => x.User);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

On line 8 (.HasOptional, .WithRequired) code contracts analysis tool produces the following two warnings "CodeContracts: Possibly calling a method on a null reference"

Any ideas how to deal with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**One option** is to mark the whole method with [ContractVerification(false)] attribute:

```
public partial class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    [ContractVerification(false)]
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasOptional(x => x.Profile).WithRequired(x => x.User);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

**Another one** is to add dozens of Contract.Assume() checks:

```
public partial class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        Contract.Assume(modelBuilder != null);

        var userEntity = modelBuilder.Entity<User>();
        Contracts.Assume(userEntity != null);
        var profileEntity = userEntity.HasOptional(x => x.Profile);
        Contracts.Assume(profileEntity != null);
        profileEntity.WithRequired(x => x.User);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Which other options do we have? Which one do you prefer?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know EF, but I believe you can't just adjust the `.Entity<User>()` function? This function doesn't specify a contract that it returns a non null value. Try something as the following:

```
var userEntity = modelBuilder.Entity<User>();
Contract.Assert( userEntity != null );
```

P.s.: I found this link which might interest you, [discussing Code Contracts and Entity Framework](http://blog.ceredir.com/index.php/2010/01/29/code-contracts-and-entity-framework/).